# How to fetch specific columns in .xls file (excel sheet) and display in jtabel and also store in mysql database in java using netbeans

Tags: java, excel

I am working on a project and stuck from one week and not found any solution .I have to upload excel sheet .xls and the software fetch specific columns in .xls file (excel sheet) and display the data in jtabel and also store in mysql database in java using netbeans . My code

```
 public String ReadCellData(int vRow, int vColumn)  
{  
String value;          //variable for storing the cell value  
Workbook wb=null;           //initialize Workbook null  
try  
{  
//reading data from a file in the form of bytes  
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("D:\\Upwork Projects\\TakeOff software by martin\\QUOTE_SCOPE.xls");  
//constructs an XSSFWorkbook object, by buffering the whole stream into the memory  
wb=new HSSFWorkbook(fis);  
}  
catch(FileNotFoundException e)  
{  
    
}  
catch(IOException e1)  
{  
}  
Sheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);   //getting the HSSFSheet object at given index  
Row row=sheet.getRow(vRow); //returns the logical row  
Cell cell=row.getCell(vColumn); //getting the cell representing the given column  
value=cell.getStringCellValue();    //getting cell value  
return value;   
  //returns the cell value  
}
```

the database code is not written yet Kindly help me in coding mysql database code or let me know that i have to change complete code or not

Comment: From your code I suspect you already tried using Apache POI. But where exactly is your problem?